# Deserialize into object with variable name

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I hope someone can help me with this; I have just started working on a website which requires to make API calls. I use an open source library for the API calls. Most of the calls work great, but I can't get the most important one to work. The json string when deserialized returns an empty object.

JSON String:

```
{"benbeun":{"id":27266833,"name":"BenBeun","profileIconId":25,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1393655593000}}
```

Call, where responseText is the above JSON string:

```
    public static T CreateRequest(string url)
    {
        var result = new T();
        var getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (var getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Default class from the library:

```
public class SummonerDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summoner ID.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Summoner name.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the summoner icon associated with the summoner.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("profileIconId")]
    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date summoner was last modified specified as epoch milliseconds.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("revisionDate")]
    public long RevisionDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Summoner level associated with the summoner.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("summonerLevel")]
    public long SummonerLevel { get; set; }

}
```

I can get the class below to work in my calls; however the 'benbeun' string is variable, so this class cannot be used.

```
public class Benbeun
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}

public class SummonerDto
{
    public Benbeun benbeun { get; set; }
}
```

Any pointers? I already tried numerous options provided in other questions, but I fear my knowledge is lacking in where exactly my problem lies. I feel I am close with the code below, however it returns an empty object aswell.

```
public class SummonerDto
{

    public IDictionary<string, Summoner> Summoner { get; set; }

}

public class Summoner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summoner ID.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Summoner name.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the summoner icon associated with the summoner.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("profileIconId")]
    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date summoner was last modified specified as epoch milliseconds.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("revisionDate")]
    public long RevisionDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Summoner level associated with the summoner.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("summonerLevel")]
    public long SummonerLevel { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Dictionary<string,Summoner>` to deserialize.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Summoner>>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems my call was wrong to deserialize this object indeed. However I'd like to not butcher my code, is there any way I can make my call stated above, work for both the old calls and this one?